# How do I set up "File Associations" in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, file-association

In **Project Properties** under Publishing in **Options** there is a tab called **"File Associations"**. I have entered there .mpg|MyDesc|MyDescID|myIco.ico. I have hoped that the mpg ext will be automatically associated after I start program. However it did not happen. Even when I choose **open with** and set the app as default it does not have the icon I have chosen.

How to use it?

I believe I have to create a published version, but I would rather not do it(since I change the app a lot). Is there any way to create the associations without creating an installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this has to do with ClickOnce deployment, and is related to file associations when a user decides to install the ClickOnce bundle for your app.

When you say "start" the program - are you referring to F5 or Ctrl+F5? If you "Publish" your ClickOnce bundle and then install from there, I believe your file associations should work.